# Laralvel 5 phpunit and model connection

Tags: php, model, phpunit, database-connection, laravel-5

In laravel I use multiple mysql connections:

`mysql`
  `mysql_web`

My models usually connect to `mysql` so that is the default connection.
Some models use the `mysql_web` connection like this:

```php
...
class AdminUser extends Model{

    protected $connection = 'mysql_web';
...
```

This works so far.

**THE PROBLEM:**

When I run my phpunit tests those tests which should use these models fails.
The error message says the base table or view does not exists. (Because it's trying to find the table in `mysql` instead of `mysql_web`)

**THE QUESTION(s):**

How can I specify which connection should these tests use. Why they can't just simply use the one I have already given them in the model classes?